# Having an issue deleting rows from server

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, rowdeleting

So in short i am having issues getting my code to remove rows from my database table "tblsurvey" when i run the code there is no errors displaying and it appears to execute the statement correctly however when checking the table i find the row has not been deleted.

```
<?php //set a question from the database V1.0
require '../configure.php'; //required to connect to the DB
//initialising variables
    $qID = ''; //question ID
    $dropDown = ''; //drop down box
    $startSelect = '<select name=drop1>'; //initial value of select
    $endSelect = '</select>'; //end of select
    $fullHTML = ''; //display the dropdown menus options
    $getDropdownID = ''; //on button submit grabs the UID for the questionairre
    $hiddenTag = '';

    $DB = "questonaire"; //must match Database
    $db_isFound = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, $DB); //connecting to the database see ../configure.php for details 

    //checking if button as been pressed -- needs to redirect to the appropriate questionaire on pressed
    if (isset($_GET['submit'])){
     //initialising the selected questionaire ID  
        $getDropdownID = $_GET['drop1'];
        //display the selected questionaire
        if ($db_isFound){
            $SQL = "DELETE FROM tblsurvey WHERE ID = ?";
            $SQL_stmt = $db_isFound->prepare($SQL);
            if($SQL_stmt){
                $SQL_stmt->bind_param("s", $qID);
                $SQL_stmt->execute();
                print("question has been successfully removed from the database.");

            }else{
                print("There was a problem running your query: row not deleted");
            }

        }else{
           print("error connecting to DB: Question not deleted");
        }
    }
```

It outputs correctly and displays

```
print("question has been successfully removed from the database.");
```

however the row is not removed from the table.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: After the execute, what is `echo $SQL_stmt->affected_rows;`? Are you sure that `$qID` is matching a record in the DB?

Comment: `$qID` is only ever assigned to empty string in this code

Comment: You aren't checking the result of the `execute()` call (or catching exceptions) before outputting that message.  So you don't actually have any sense of whether the query was successful or not.

Comment: **Error checking** but if you cannot be bothered, Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`
 to the top of your script. This will force any mysqli_ errors to generate an Exception that you can see on the browser as well as normal PHP errors.

Comment: @user3407086 What SQL do you mean this sql `$SQL = "DELETE FROM tblsurvey WHERE ID = ?";`

Answer (score 1):

in this line

```
$SQL_stmt->bind_param("s", $qID);
```

replace `$qID` for `$getDropdownID`  because I don't see where `$qID` get value.

Comment: Yes, thank you I came to the realisation just 5 mins before you responded. thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for taking a look i had a bit of a brain fart and was calling the wrong var in the prepared statement the fix was

```
$SQL_stmt->bind_param("i", $getDropdownID);
```